# spring-cloud-contract-wiremock | Registering Stubs Automatically vs Programmatically

Tags: java, testing, mocking, wiremock, spring-cloud-contract

I would like to continue loanding all my subs

```java
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0, stubs = "classpath:/mappings/perform-buyback")
```

And in some test cases on this test class, I would like to change some mock responses to simulate different scenarios.

When I run only my local test method it works fine, when I run all my class it fails. So I come to this question. Is that possible to overwrite some stub that was registered [according to the documentation automatically](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/project-features.html#features-wiremock-registering-stubs) and replace it with `stubFor(get(urlEqualTo(` programmatic in each method? What should be the behaver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it cause if you do `new WireMockServer(...)` you can pass in a port of a running WireMock instance and then you can run any logic you want. You can manually stub it, reset it, do whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you for your time @marcin-grzejszczak
In the end, it was a problem of mutability that was obfuscating me to solve the issue.
With my question here I was trying to understand if this is an expected behaver or what I was trying to do was an error but it works really well.
I can use the automatically registered stubs and programmatically replace them when needed.